# Pegar script de uma DIV com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

É possivel pegar o SCRIPT de algum elemento.. EX:

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Pegar apartir da 'class="box"'</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

pegar o código completo dentro da divisória `id="form"`? Que seria:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Pegar apartir da 'class="box"'</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se por "script" você quer dizer pegar todo o HTML dentro da div, faça assim:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var conteudo = form.innerHTML;
alert(conteudo);
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Pegar apartir da 'class="box"'</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brigadão mano ;)

Answer (score 0):

Como a pergunta está na categoria "jQuery" vou dar a resposta em jQuery:

```
var div_form = $('#form');
var html = div_form.html();
```

se você fizer

```
console.log(html);
```

você verá o código html extraído do elemento #form.

Você pode usar a versão simplificada:

```
var html = $('#form').html();
```